# .htaccess to redirect url query strings

Tags: .htaccess

I just want to have a nicer URL for our website, I have a query strings and I want to make like this if it's possible.

My original URL:
https://minedbp.com/busact.php?ba=36&act=banking-finance

I want to become like this but with 301 redirect.
https://minedbp.com/banking-finance

is it possible without loosing the value for our parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This must work :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /busact.php?ba=$2&act=$1 [L]
```

This transform the following URL

> https://minedbp.com/busact.php?ba=36&act=banking-finance

in

> https://minedbp.com/banking-finance/36

Comment: I have tried just now, it seems it's not changing the URL to my desired result. And one more thing, how can I pass the parameters to .htaccess? these are all dynamic values.  thanks

Comment: Sorry, but still it seems it's not working. Thanks for the quick response.